# System of linear recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

During some computations I came up with the following system of linear recurrences:

$$B_{n+2} = 3B_n + A_n \\
A_n = A_{n-1} + B_{n-1}$$

Here I am trying to find the solution for $B$ (hoping to get some sort of homogeneous equation, find it roots and get the closed form formula).

But I can't solve it. The only thing I can do is $$B_{n+2} = 3B_n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i$$, which will not help me to solve recurrence.

So is there a way I can find $B$ without the summation through $n$?

Comment: What does this recurrence count?  Perhaps there is an easier to solve recurrence that can be found by approaching the problem from a different angle.

Comment: @JMoravitz recurrence counts one of the problems in the online course, so I would rather not to post it at least now. May be there is a way to count it in other way, but if it is not, is there a way to solve this system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the above equations into equations only in $A$ and only in $B$:
The second equation gives
$$
B_n = A_{n+1} - A_n
$$
applying this to the first equation gives
$$
A_{n+3} - A_{n+2} = 3(A_{n+1} - A_n) + A_n = 3 A_{n+1} - 2 A_n \Rightarrow \\
A_{n+3} = A_{n+2} + 3 A_{n+1} - 2 A_n
$$
Similar
$$
A_n = B_{n+2} - 3 B_n \\
B_{n+2} - 3 B_n = B_{n+1} - 3 B_{n-1} + B_{n-1} \Rightarrow \\
B_{n+2} = B_{n+1} + 3 B_n - 2 B_{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

the equation 
$$B_{n+2} = 3B_n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i$$

is of the form 
$$B \ast h (n)= 0$$
 where $h(n) = \delta(n+2) - 2\delta(n) - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \delta(n)$ is a linear filter. the general way to solve this is similar as the method of using the Laplace transform for solving linear differential equations.  [the discrete version of the Laplace transform is the the Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) :

$$H(z) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty z^{-n} h(n) = z^{-2} - 2 - \frac{1}{1-z} =
\frac{z^{-2}-z^{-1}-3+2z}{1-z}$$
$$\frac{1}{H(z)} =\frac{1-z}{1-z-3z^2+2z^3} = \frac{(1-z)}{(2z-1)(z^2-z-1)}$$
[perform partial fraction decomposition to get :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)
$$\frac{1}{H(z)} = -\frac{1}{5 (z-1/2)}+\frac{z-3}{5 (-1-z+z^2)} = -\frac{1}{5 (z-1/2)} + \frac{A}{z-\varphi}+\frac{B}{z-\varphi}$$
for some constants $A,B$ and $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. the solution is then :
$$g(n) = -\frac{1}{10}2^{-n}_{\quad n \ge 1} + A\varphi^{n-1}_{\quad n \ge 1} + B\varphi^{-n+1}_{\quad n \ge 1}$$
with 
$$g \ast h(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty g(m) h(n-m) = \delta(n)$$

i.e. $g(n)$ is the solution of your difference equation for initial condition $B(n) = 0$ for $n < 0$ and $B(0) = 1$, the solution for other initial condition being found by linearity.